# iOS Cordova App not showing version updates available

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect

Currently when making a new release android customers are given a notification that a new version of the is available for download.

I have searched for solutions on here (stackoverflow) but the only related answers are for apps developed in xcode.

How can I notify customers when releasing a new version of the app to itunes?

Comment: AFAIK you'll have to manually push a notification - there's nothing that I've seen that will automatically take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the current app version in your database and use appVersion plugin to get the installed version on the device. Then you can compare the versions (on start-up e.g.) and notify the user somehow that there is a new version available. You can even provide add link to your app in App Store.

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/WellBload/cordova-plugin-app-version/blob/4234061/README.md

It does require some maintenance because you have to update your database every time the update has been released. The choice is yours.